# Variable displaying single quote when trying to escape double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, double-quotes

I have the following script.

```
    #!/apps/queue/bin/ksh93
    
    set -x
    OPTIONS="test \"select * from testoptions\""
    
    mytest "${OPTIONS}"
```

On executing the script, the output is displayed as
[myuser]$ ./test.sh
**+ OPTIONS='test "select * from testoptions"'

- mytest 'test "select * from testoptions"'**
  ./test.sh[6]: mytest: not found [No such file or directory]

Ignoring, the last line error, I am not sure why the second line of my output is displayed within single quotes after the string mytest.

Please assist.

**Expected output:**

[myuser]$ ./test.sh

- OPTIONS='test "select * from testoptions"'
- **mytest test "select * from testoptions"**
  ./test.sh[6]: mytest: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: Why do you want them to show with double quotes as opposed to single? It will make no difference to the execution in this case?

Comment: @BikerBoy : Because `set -x` was designed in that way. Would you prefer seeing other quotes instead?